# Hashable type: list error in if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to count the amount of words in a file and then putting them into a dictionary to count the frequency of the word if it is repeated. In the if-statement that checks if the word already exists in the dictionary, I get an unhashable type error. [this is my code and what the error it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOa83.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the type of the variables

`line` is a string, separated by spaces

`temp` is a list of strings

`words` now is [[string1, string2, ...], [], ...]

Now the `i` is a also a list of string (a `temp`)

You are trying to do `if i in WordCount`

Since WordCount is a dictionary/set, it attemps to call `hash(i)` and check if the hash is in WordCount (That's how dictionary works)

And since `i` is a list which is *unhashable*, it returns the error!

Hope it helps :)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

I think you want the `words` to contain the individual words? If so, replace `words.append(temp)` with `words += temp`, as you can add a list to list

Comment: How would you recommend I fix the error? Would I have to create a new variable to go through dictionary?

Comment: I think you want the `words` to contain the individual words? If so, replace `words.append(temp)` with `words += temp`, as you can add a list to list